# How can I set maximum and minimum limit of scaling?

Tags: jquery, css, transform, scaling, translate

I'm zooming and moving a div using transform translate and scale.
https://jsfiddle.net/Taimurofficial/z78ukb6g/7/
Here is the code:

```
var scale = 1,
panning = false,
pointX = 0,
pointY = 0,
start = { x: 0, y: 0 },
zoom = document.getElementById("zoom");

function setTransform() {
zoom.style.transform = "translate(" + pointX + "px, " + pointY + "px) scale(" + scale + ")";
}

zoom.onmousedown = function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
start = { x: e.clientX - pointX, y: e.clientY - pointY };
panning = true;
}

zoom.onmouseup = function (e) {
panning = false;
}

zoom.onmousemove = function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
if (!panning) {
  return;
}
pointX = (e.clientX - start.x);
pointY = (e.clientY - start.y);
setTransform();
}

zoom.onwheel = function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var xs = (e.clientX - pointX) / scale,
  ys = (e.clientY - pointY) / scale,
  delta = (e.wheelDelta ? e.wheelDelta : -e.deltaY);
(delta > 0) ? (scale *= 1.2) : (scale /= 1.2);
pointX = e.clientX - xs * scale;
pointY = e.clientY - ys * scale;

setTransform();
}
```

I just want to turn off negative scaling.

Comment: I can't see anything that would make scale negative. Do you mean you don't want it to go below a certain value? If so, just test whether scale/1.2 is too small and don't update scale with it. Am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: It's default scale is 1. I want to stop scale going down to minus for example -1.5 otherwise it can be soo small if I zoom out too much.

Comment: scale cannot go minus given the code you have got because it’s just divided each time by a constant. It can of course go very small and you can stop that by testing its new value before you update it.

Comment: Okay. And How to do so?

Comment: Test its valu before you update it using e.g. a JS if.

Comment: I actually not that good with js. I got this code from codepen and it worked. It will be life saving if you answer this by editing that code! I really appreciate your helpfulness though.